# Is there a way to use wp_enqueue_script for adding JavaScript directly?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way of adding Javascript to a page directly but having Wordpress to wait for jQuery to load? Just as with using `wp_enqueue_script`?

In the custom page template I have the following code:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'newly_created') : ?>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            App.dialogs.afterPetitionCreate();
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Wordpress barks that $ is undefined. Now I do not want to load a entire .js file just to call that function. So in that sense `wp_enqueue_script` isn't an option. I only want to fire some JavaScript directly on the page but I do want to wait for jQuery to load.

This is what I also tried, adding the JavaScript to the footer with Wordpress:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'newly_created') :
    add_action('wp_footer', 'my_footer_scripts');
    function my_footer_scripts() { ?>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                App.dialogs.afterPetitionCreate();
            });
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But unfortunately the same error appears `$ is undefined`.
So what would be the correct way to quickly load some Javascript on a custom Wordpress page template AND wait for jQuery to load?

Comment: The javascript code added in footer should work. You just need to use jQuery instead of $. 
Try below code


 `add_action('wp_footer', 'my_footer_scripts');

    function my_footer_scripts() { ?>
        <script>
(function($) {
            $(function () {
                App.dialogs.afterPetitionCreate();
            });
}(jQuery));
        </script>
    <?php } ?>`

For more information check link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2895/not-defined-using-jquery-in-wordpress

Comment: The function will want to use is **wp_add_inline_script()**. Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up writing, and does exactly what I want. Like Submit Parkash mentioned, jQuery needs to be used instead of $.

```
/*
 * Adds a single bit of Javascript to the page.
 */
function theme_embed_script($script) {
    add_action('wp_footer', function ($script) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . $script . '</script>';
    }, 10);
    do_action('wp_footer', $script);
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php theme_embed_script('jQuery(function () { alert("Hello"); });'); ?>
```

OR use Wordpress' `wp_add_inline_script()` script like David mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a good practice.

It is better to change logic to something like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'newly_created') : ?>
    <input type='hidden' id='status' name='status' value='newly_created'>
<?php endif; ?>
```

script.js:

```
$(function() {
    if ( $('#status').val() === 'newly_created' ) {
        App.dialogs.afterPetitionCreate()
    }
});
```

and

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'afterPetitionCreate', '/path/to/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
```

p.s. you can wrap `wp_enqueue_script()` into `is_page_template( 'my-cool-page-teplate.php' )`.

Comment: Loading an entire JS file (that requires an extra GET request) for a few lines of JavaScript isn't optimal either. But I do like the approach of listening for a hidden input value. And calling JS functions based on that. +1

Comment: JS does not require GET parameters.
So let your server render a document based on GET, and client's browser do JS logic.

Comment: I mean that with `wp_enqueue_script` you add another JS file to the document. That needs a GET request to get loaded. That slows down the website. You usually don't want to do a extra GET request just for a few lines of JavaScript.

Comment: agree. you can include this small part into a main.min.js and call this function if input field is present.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the script within the document ready event like the following code below?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(function () {
      App.dialogs.afterPetitionCreate();
   });
});
</script>
```

The .ready event occurs when the object of the document or the DOM is loaded which makes it perfect to place all of your jquery events and other functions.

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't work.  $(function () { }); is identical to jQuery's ready() function.

Comment: Have you checked if the script you have added is injected after jquery.js? if so, make sure there is no `async` attribute on the script tag.